# Simple home modem/router routing

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have simple home modem/router Thomson TWG870. Here are my questions:

1. How can i get to know what routing mode - static or dynamic the router uses?
2. If the router uses dynamic routing how to know what protocol/version it uses (RIP1, RIP2 etc.)
3. There is an option "RIP support" under "advanced" modem settings. The default value for this is "disabled". Does it mean that the router just use static routing? If so how can i view/edit the routing table?

Comment: looking at the manual (http://setuprouter.com/router/thomson/twg-870/manual-703.pdf) I cant find options for setting static routes, only using rip to advertise.

Comment: If you didn't configure any dynamic routing, you probably don't have any. Most typical SoHo router configurations use only interface routes and a default route.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So does it mean that this router have some static, simple routing table hardcoded which cannot be changed/edited?

Comment: @Lister So does it mean that this router have some static, simple routing table hardcoded which cannot be changed/edited?

Comment: Most routers allow you to edit their static routes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So why did You previously said "Most typical SoHo router configurations use only interface routes and a default route" suggesting (in my understanding) that in most SoHo routers the routing table is fixed and cannot be edited?

Comment: You asked how to know what routing mode the router was actually using, not what its capabilities were. So I answered about what the vast majority of SoHo routers are actually doing.

Comment: @David Schwartz So do i understand right that vast majority of SoHo routers have sth. like a default routing table which consists of only interface routes and a default route but such the default can be edited?

Comment: That's right. Most SoHo routers at least let you add static routes.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a router such as this will have a static default route to forward all external traffic out the WAN port. Your internal network will have a route due to being directly connected. This is not something that will typically be advertised on the Web GUI of a home modem/router.

RIP support may be available but most likely currently disabled.

Comment: So does it mean that this router have some static, simple routing table hardcoded which cannot be changed/edited?

Comment: @Mulligan Where are you getting that from? Your question was not about what routers *could* do, nor was this answer. So why are you drawing conclusions about capabilities?